# Taxonomy template shows only 10 posts

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

So I'm a little confused with this one.

A blog I recently set up makes plenty of use of custom post types and custom taxonomies.

In the reading settings the blog posts to show is at 100 but I can find no where to tell taxonomy pages to show 100 posts and they are stuck at 10.

How do I change it without messing around with custom `get_posts();` or extensive `query_posts();`

I have tried:

A custom `query_posts();` loop

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by removing the taxnomy.php page and let it fall back to index.php

Comment: That doesn't explain anything. Can you tell _why_ it works now and why it didn’t work before?

Comment: I don't know why it works it just does and it's the only thing that worked

Answer (score 2):

Sorry - this is probably an obvious answer but without seeing your query_posts query it's hard to say if you've tried this or not. As you're altering the main query on the page query_posts should be the right tool for the job.

Something like the following query should work:

```
<?php query_posts( 'posts_per_page=100' ); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
// Something before posts display
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
// Post Content
<?php endwhile; ?>
// Something after the loop                     
<?php else: ?>
// Something in case there are no posts
<?php endif;?>
```

If you've already tried this can you edit your answer to show the code you're using?  Also are you using any custom taxonomy templates or are all taxonomies going through taxonomy.php?

Comment: That would be the obvious answer to what my query_posts(); did.

Comment: OK, so which template are you intending to use to display your results? Have you set up a specific taxonomy template or are you using something more generic like taxonomy.php or archive.php?

Comment: taxonomy.php template.